# Two column layout for two forms, with alignment between submit buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use HTML+CSS to create a two column layout to display two parallel forms.  I would like the input fields of the forms to flow naturally down each column, except the two submit buttons, which look bad when they are not at the same height as each other.

I have tried a few different techniques, to no avail:

HTML tables work for creating the layout, but because elements are grouped logically by the row, it's not possible to have separate forms which encompass each column. (One of the columns has a file upload, so one big form is a no-go).

CSS tables are no good for similar reasons.

Using divs with "float: left" and "float:right" respectively works for the layout, and is very nice for grouping the two forms.  However, the submit buttons (Which are the last elements of the divs) are at different heights.  I would like to move the higher button down to the height of the lower button, so they are vertically aligned.  However, I can't seem to figure out any way to do this, because they are two sibling divs, so they aren't "aware" of each other's heights.

Here is an example JSFiddle of the float-based implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/53nvqrfr/

```
<div style="float: left; width:50%">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type=" text " />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type=" text " />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit ">submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:50%">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type=" text " />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit ">submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide any showcase ?

Comment: Post your code Jeremy

Comment: I added an example implementation to the question.

Comment: The option is to use javascript to calculate the biggest height of the two  parent divs and set the shorter div's height to taller div's height. then align the buttons to bottom using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap like this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/cag3diNYLD) and if you want full width just change class name from container to container-fluid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty row to the second table. It might be a hack, but it works.